# Vector erase iterator outside of range

Tags: c++, opengl, vector, glut

[link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7MaiC_Cj3XsUFJRZG1rRXdwQTA) to the project 
I am creating a small glut application that will draw circuit components.
I have a class called "Component" that looks like that:

```
// nextIndex is the index of the next component to be created
int Component::nextIndex = 0;
Component::Component( void ){
setType( RESISTOR );
setValue( 0.0 );
setX( 0.0 );
setY( 0.0 );
setSize( 2.0 );
setIndex( nextIndex );
}

eType Component::getType( void ){return cType}
double Component::getValue( void ){return cValue;}
double Component::getX( void ){return cX;}
double Component::getY( void ){return cY;}
double Component::getSize( void ){return cSize;}
void Component::setType( eType type ){cType = type;}
void Component::setValue( double value ){cValue = value;}
void Component::setX( double x){cX = x;}
void Component::setY( double y ){cY = y;}
void Component::setSize( double size ){cSize = size;}
int Component::getIndex( void ){return index;}
void Component::setIndex( int n ){index = n;}
```

NOTE: I am incrementing the nextIndex every time I create a new instance of the class.
Here is my other class which has a vector of Components and handles the addition and deletion of the components:

```
class OGWindow{
private:

    bool LINK, DELETE;
    int linkNo;
    ...
    Component currentSquare;
    Component *currentSquarePtr, *linkSquPtr1, *linkSquPtr2;
    double squareXStart, squareYStart, squareXEnd, squareYEnd;
    std::vector< Component > compVector;

public:
    ...
    void myMouseClick(int button, int state, int x, int y);
    ...
    void deleteSquare( Component *squPtr );
};
```

I am creating components to the window fine like that:
    int NEXT_INT = 0;

```
if (x >= createButtonX && x <= createButtonX + createButtonWidth) {
    cout << "Clicked Create button" << endl;
    Component *compPtr = new Component;
    compPtr->setX(0.0);
    compPtr->setY(0.0);
    compPtr->setIndex(NEXT_INT);
    NEXT_INT++;

    compVector.push_back(*compPtr);
    //------------SET THE CURRENT SQUARE TO THE NEWLY CREATED COMPONENT-----
    vector<Component>::iterator constIterator;
    for (constIterator = compVector.begin(); constIterator != compVector.end(); ++constIterator){
        currentSquarePtr = &(*constIterator);
    }
    cout << "Vector size:  " << compVector.size() << endl;
    glutPostRedisplay();
}
```

But when I am deleting, it deletes some of the elements and at the last one I get the "vector out of range" error:

```
void OGWindow::deleteSquare( Component *squPtr ) {
    compVector.erase(compVector.begin() + (squPtr->getIndex()));
cout << "Vector size:  " << compVector.size() << endl;
glutPostRedisplay();
}
```

Please share any ideas why this is happening.

Comment: Did you check the result of `squPtr->getIndex()` in the debugger?

Comment: Please create a [mcve]. The only relevant field is `getIndex()`, so all of these `double`s are irrelevant to the problem.

Comment: You have a memory leak in the code you show: You allocate memory and make `compPtr` point to it, then you *copy* the object into the vector (so you don't really need a pointer at all) and then you forget to `delete` the pointer.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ yes, it is 2 just before the erase (when I have only  one component in the vector)

Comment: Also, where do you call `setIndex`? What argument to you pass to `setIndex`?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg nowhere, I am not calling it.

Comment: I have included a link to the VB project at the top. @Barry

Comment: The [mcve] must be **in the question**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's massive memory leaking going on when you create components. You allocate a new Component on the heap, and then put a copy of that into the `std::vector`. After scope exit, the pointer that was pointing to the new component on the heap is lost forever.

Just create components on the stack, add those to your vector and you'll be fine.

Furthermore, indices start at 0, not at 1:

```
int Component::nextIndex = 1;
```

should be

```
int Component::nextIndex = 0;
```

But this is a design mistake anyway; when you remove a component from your `std::vector`, you will have to update *all* the indices of the components that are lying after the deleted component (you need to decrease their value by 1).

It would be better if you start thinking in terms of iterators instead of pointers. I'm guessing you want the following: just a gigantic global datastructure where all the components reside. This could be an `std::list<Component> compList`. Then forget about managing indices and pointers, and use `std::list<Component>::iterator` everywhere instead of `Component*`. Removing a component is then safe, simply by doing

```
void OGWindow::deleteSquare( std::list<Component>::iterator squPtr ) {
    compList.erase(squPtr);
    cout << "List size:  " << compList.size() << endl;
    glutPostRedisplay();
}
```

and to add a component

```
if (x >= createButtonX && x <= createButtonX + createButtonWidth) {
    cout << "Clicked Create button" << endl;
    Component comp;
    comp.setX(0.0);
    comp.setY(0.0);

    // Notice how we put the new component at the front
    // instead of the back.
    compList.push_front(comp);

    //------------SET THE CURRENT SQUARE TO THE NEWLY CREATED COMPONENT-----
    // easy now!
    currentSquarePtr = compList.begin();

    cout << "List size:  " << compList.size() << endl;
    glutPostRedisplay();
}
```

Remember, change these

```
Component *currentSquarePtr;
Component *linkSquPtr1;
Component *linkSquPtr2;
```

to these

```
std::list<Component>::iterator currentSquarePtr;
std::list<Component>::iterator linkSquPtr1;
std::list<Component>::iterator linkSquPtr2;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer. I am going to test the suggested changes now.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few problems with your indexing of the `Component` objects.

First of all indexes into vectors are like arrays, i.e. based on zero. So if you have a vector with only one element the index (and offset from the `begin()` iterator) is *zero*. Anything else is out of bounds.

You seem to have a `static` member variable that you use for the next index, and you initialize that variable to `1` which will always be wrong first index in a vector. Then in the `Component` constructor you increase this static `nextIndex` variable causing the second object you create to have index `2` but in the vector it will have index `1` (if you have both objects in the vector).

Another problem comes when you remove the objects from the vector. Besides the (now obvious) problem using the wrong index, you don't renumber the index in the vector. So if you have two elements in the vector with the (wrong) indexes `1` and `2`, and remove the first then the new first element will have the even wronger index `2`.

My suggestion to solve this problem is to not use indexes at all, but instead implement a comparison operator for equality. Then you can use e.g. [`std::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) to find the object in the vector, and then call `erase` with the correct iterator returned by `std::find`.

Then the `deleteSquare` would look something like

```
void OGWindow::deleteSquare( Component const &squRef ) {
    auto iterator = std::find( std::begin(compVector), std::end(compVector), squRef);

    if (iterator != std::end(compVector))
        compVector.erase(iterator);

    cout << "Vector size:  " << compVector.size() << endl;
    glutPostRedisplay();
}
```